# Adding a short example after explaining the part of the method

Tags: writing

I am writing my paper's (social science) methodology part and it consists of several steps that I express mathematically. However, I have a feeling that one of the steps might be better explained if I also add some kind of an example to it right after formulas.
How acceptable is it in academia? Generally, does it mean that I have to explain my methods in a way they do not need an extra explanation?

I intend to publish this paper (maybe this is irrelevant, adding as extra info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples can be useful. How many examples should be in a formal paper varies from area to area, and even from journal to journal. For example, in pure math, I've had some papers where examples have been considered completely acceptable, and at least one paper where the editors took out ones they considered unhelpful or overly verbose. In general, if you think the examples would be helpful, then put them in. The worst that can happen is a referee or editor makes you take them out later.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrating your method with a brief example is perfectly acceptable, especially if you do it in a reader-friendly way. Indeed, paragraphs often start with a "topic sentence" (which introduce the main idea, e.g. a concise description of your method), followed by some "supporting sentences" (which substantiate your main idea, e.g. by providing examples), before ending with a "concluding sentence". Such a paragraph structure enhances readability - so go for it!

Answer (score 1):

> How acceptable is it in academia?

There shouldn't be an issue with this. While I'm not from the social science field, I've seen numerous papers that add figures or short examples that illustrate the theoretical concepts discussed. These are really helpful when the way methods are described carries a little too much abstraction and the reader isn't comfortable with it. If you feel the way you described the concept is too abstract or if you feel an example would help the overall understanding of the concept, then go right ahead with adding an example.

> Generally, does it mean that I have to explain my methods in a way they do not need an extra explanation?

Yes... and no. Yes because its good to aim for a way to explain your methods such that there is no need for extra explanation. I generally think this is something that should be sought after when writing about one's methods. However, no because I don't think you can always generalize how the community will understand your writing. Thinking about this too much (i.e. trying to achieve perfection) can lead you to a writer's block.

Its a good idea to keep in mind the venue which you plan to publish. If you're writing for a community / venue that's specific to your topic, then I don't think you need to keep this in mind so much. But if you're writing for a more general community, then maybe there should be more effort to scrutinize how your writing style might be interpreted by others not so familiar with your field.

At the end of the day, when you submit your paper for publication, the reviewers should be able to point out if something is too vague or if there is too much information. Write the way you feel comfortable expressing your ideas and base the amount of explanation off of other papers similar to yours (if there are any).

Comment: I am writing for management community and my methods include the usage of combinatorics and dynamic programming. I guess in this case, it is better to try and make methodology part as understandable as possible

Answer (score 1):

There is not a problem, it will not be seen as a negative and sometimes reviewers request an example or some simulations, graphs, alternatives etc to be added to a paper. You can use both artificial numbers and real world data, and if you can end up with a nice graph the better.

> Generally, does it mean that I have to explain my methods in a way they do not need an extra explanation?

In theory yes, in practice that can be very difficult or even impossible and just showing how the mechanics work saves the author from rewriting all the time and the reviewer from trying to understand unfamiliar, or even arcane, methodologies. An alternative to an example is a sequence of rudimentary cases which are easy to grasp, each time a new element is introduced and it builds up to the main model with the most important results.